# Expose object properties dynamically

Tags: python

```
In [1]: class Foo():
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: class Qux():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         item = Foo()
   ...:         

In [3]: a = Foo()

In [4]: setattr(a, 'superpower', 'strength')

In [5]: a.superpower
Out[5]: 'strength'

In [6]: b = Qux()

In [7]: b.item = a

In [8]: b.superpower
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-cf0e287006f1> in <module>()
----> 1 b.superpower

AttributeError: Qux instance has no attribute 'superpower'
```

What I would like is to define some way of calling any attribute on Qux and have it return `getattr(Qux.item, <attributename>)`. In other words, to have `b.superpower` work **without** explicitly defining:

```
@property
def superpower(self):
    return getattr(self.item, 'superpower')
```

I don't want to lose access to any properties defined on `Qux` itself as well, but rather to expose properties defined on `Foo` if they are not also on `Qux`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class Qux(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = Foo()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.item, attr)
```

`__getattr__` gets called whenever someone tries to look up an attribute of the object, but fails through normal means.

It has an evil twin called `__getattribute__`, which *always* gets called and must be used with extreme caution.

Comment: @Vishal Using `__getattr__` already does exactly that, see the doc linked in both our answers

Comment: Can I use `__setattr__` similarly to set an attribute only if it is already defined (`__dict__`?) and set it on `self.item` if not?

Comment: Yes. When you know it is defined already, make sure not to `setattr()` directly, because that will trigger your `__setattr__` method again. Instead, call `super().__setattr__(self, attr, val)`.

Answer (score 2):

You do that by defining [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), not with a property. For any attribute that *cannot be found* with the standard protocol, Python will call the `__getattr__` method of a class.

Moreover, to store the `item`, you have to assign it to `self.item`, otherwise it is thrown at the end of `Qux.__init__`.

Finally, inheriting from `Foo` seems unecessary in that case.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, superpower):
        self.superpower = superpower

class Qux:
    def __init__(self, foo_item):
        self.item = foo_item

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.item, name)
```

### Example

```
f = Foo('strenght')
q = Qux(f)
print(q.superpower) # 'strenght'
```

## Inheritance

Although, it seems you half-tried to implement this with inheritance. If your intent was to extend `Qux` behaviour with `Foo`, then inheritance would be the way to go.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, superpower):
        self.superpower = superpower

class Qux(Foo):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.item, name)
```

### Example

```
q = Qux('strenght')
print(q.superpower)  # 'strenght'
```

Comment: I picked the other one only because it was answered first. Both answers work for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Vishal Sure thing. Glad we could help!